# How do I change this Raphael drawn pie chart, so that the colors dont change

Tags: jquery, drawing, geometry, vector-graphics, graphael

I'm trying to change this pie chart, so that when I click on a segment, the color of the different segments don't change. I see that the fill has a direct relationship with the shape of the segment, but I totally suck. Please help! You can see the pie chart in action here:

http://raphaeljs.com/growing-pie.html

```
function drawgrowingpie () {
    var r = Raphael("holder");

    r.customAttributes.segment = function (x, y, r, a1, a2) {
        var flag = (a2 - a1) > 180,
            clr = (a2 - a1) / 360;
        a1 = (a1 % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
        a2 = (a2 % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
        return {
            path: [["M", x, y], ["l", r * Math.cos(a1), r * Math.sin(a1)], ["A", r, r, 0, +flag, 1, x + r * Math.cos(a2), y + r * Math.sin(a2)], ["z"]],
            fill: "hsb(" + clr + ", .75, .8)"
        };
    };

    function animate(ms) {
        var start = 0,
            val;
        for (i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
            val = 360 / total * data[i];
            paths[i].animate({segment: [200, 200, 150, start, start += val]}, ms || 1500, "bounce");
            paths[i].angle = start - val / 2;
        }
    }

    var data = [24, 92, 24, 52, 78, 99, 82, 27],
        paths = r.set(),
        total,
        start,
        bg = r.circle(200, 200, 0).attr({stroke: "#fff", "stroke-width": 4});
    data = data.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a;});

    total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, ii = data.length; i < ii; i++) {
        total += data[i];
    }
    start = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
        var val = 360 / total * data[i];
        (function (i, val) {
            paths.push(r.path().attr({segment: [200, 200, 1, start, start + val], stroke: "#fff"}).click(function () {
                total += data[i];
                data[i] *= 2;
                animate();
            }));
        })(i, val);
        start += val;
    }
    bg.animate({r: 151}, 1000, "bounce");
    animate(1000);
};
```

Comment: just changing the fill hsb value. although it keeps the colors constant, it of course, makes all the segments the same color. I'd like all the different segments to be different colors, but retain their fill, even as they grow or shrink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
return {
    // snip...
    fill: "hsb(" + clr + ", .75, .8)"
};
```

to something else, or remove the `fill` property entirely from the returned object.

---

Here's a nudge in the right direction: instead of changing the color every time a slice is animated, the color is now passed to the `segment` function. This means that the two different callers (the initializer and the click handler) can control the color differently. The `segment` function is changed to not return *any* `fill` information if no `clr` (color) was passed to it. This means the color is unchanged by the `click` handler, since only the initialization code passes color information.

Hopefully this makes sense to you.

```
function drawgrowingpie() {
    var r = Raphael("holder");
                                                        // ↓↓↓ pass the color
    r.customAttributes.segment = function(x, y, r, a1, a2, clr) {
        var flag = (a2 - a1) > 180;
        a1 = (a1 % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
        a2 = (a2 % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
        var props = {
            path: [["M", x, y], ["l", r * Math.cos(a1), r * Math.sin(a1)], ["A", r, r, 0, +flag, 1, x + r * Math.cos(a2), y + r * Math.sin(a2)], ["z"]]
        };

        // only return fill properties if the color was passed
        if (clr) {
            props.fill = "hsb(" + clr + ", .75, .8)";
            console.log(clr);
        }
        return props;
    };

    function animate(ms) {
        var start = 0,
            val;
        for (i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
            val = 360 / total * data[i];
            paths[i].animate({
                // notice that no color data is passed here...
                segment: [200, 200, 150, start, start += val]
            }, ms || 1500, "bounce");
            paths[i].angle = start - val / 2;
        }
    }

    var data = [24, 92, 24, 52, 78, 99, 82, 27],
        paths = r.set(),
        total, start, bg = r.circle(200, 200, 0).attr({
            stroke: "#fff",
            "stroke-width": 4
        });
    data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a;
    });

    total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, ii = data.length; i < ii; i++) {
        total += data[i];
    }
    start = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
        var val = 360 / total * data[i];
        (function(i, val) {
            paths.push(r.path().attr({
                // ...but we do pass color data here      ↓↓↓↓  
                segment: [200, 200, 1, start, start + val, val],
                stroke: "#fff"
            }).click(function() {
                total += data[i];
                data[i] *= 2;
                animate();
            }));
        })(i, val);
        start += val;
    }
    bg.animate({
        r: 151
    }, 1000, "bounce");
    animate(1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/xsfQj/

Comment: i've tried messing with it, but it leaves all the segments the same color. i figure the color of segments are tied to the variable, clr, which is a function of the shape of the segments. I think in this case, the circle will have to be redrawn. removing the fill property leaves me with no fill at all, which makes it difficult to click on the segments to animate them. Thanks for your help, this site is amazing.

Comment: You could hack around this by storing the initial `clr` value for each segment (use an array or an object), and retrieve that `clr` value later, though it would not be terribly elegant.

Comment: See my edit. Let me know if you can't understand what I've done.

Comment: Thanks for all your help in getting me so much closer to my desired result. I really am a total javascript/jquery noob, but i'm finding that things are starting to sink in the longer i stare at it.